# How to find slop using two points using bitmap?

Tags: android

i am trying to find slope of lines that i draw on image.[i want to find slop of given lines on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRm38.jpg)

(but thist is on touch event i want to calculate slope as camera moves its code for a robot .camera is on head of robot and it will move in corridor if slop of both line in given image is same that means robot is in center i want answer in that case by using red color tiles .and calculation will not be on touch event but by changing image position on run time)i have use bitmap to find color of each pixel. My aim as red color tile start note that point (a) and then similarly find point (b) to calculate slop of line. Same for line on other side.this is my code i have done so far.I am new pardon if i stating question wrong.thanks in advance

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction()== event.ACTION_DOWN||event.getAction()== event.ACTION_MOVE)
            {
                bmp=image.getDrawingCache();
                int wi=bmp.getWidth();
                int hi=bmp.getHeight();
                int x= (int) event.getX();
                int y= (int) event.getY();
                int pixel=bmp.getPixel((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY());
                int a=bmp.getPixel((int)event.getX()-1,(int)event.getY()+1);
                int b=bmp.getPixel((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY()+1);
                int c=bmp.getPixel((int)event.getX()+1,(int)event.getY()+1);
                int d=bmp.getPixel((int)event.getX()-1,(int)event.getY());
                int e=bmp.getPixel((int)event.getX()+1,(int)event.getY());
                int f=bmp.getPixel((int)event.getX()-1,(int)event.getY()-1);
                int g=bmp.getPixel((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY()-1);
                int h=bmp.getPixel((int)event.getX()+1,(int)event.getY()-1);
                //Pixel
                int Red= Color.red(pixel);
                int Green=Color.green(pixel);
                int Blue= Color.blue(pixel);
                int avg=Green+Blue/3;

                int Ra= Color.red(a);
                int Ga=Color.green(a);
                int Ba= Color.blue(a);
                int avgA=Ga+Ba/3;
                //b
                int Rb= Color.red(b);
                int Gb=Color.green(b);
                int Bb= Color.blue(b);
                int avgB=+Gb+Bb/3;
                //c
                int Rc= Color.red(c);
                int Gc=Color.green(c);
                int Bc= Color.blue(c);
                int avgC=Gc+Bc/3;
                //d
                int Rd= Color.red(d);
                int Gd=Color.green(d);
                int Bd= Color.blue(d);
                int avgD=Gd+Bd/3;
                //e
                int Re= Color.red(e);
                int Ge=Color.green(e);
                int Be= Color.blue(e);
                int avgE=Ge+Be/3;
                //f
                int Rf= Color.red(f);
                int Gf=Color.green(f);
                int Bf= Color.blue(f);
                int avgF=Gf+Bf/3;
                //g
                int Rg= Color.red(g);
                int Gg=Color.green(g);
                int Bg= Color.blue(g);
                int avgG=Gg+Bg/3;
                //h
                int Rh= Color.red(h);
                int Gh=Color.green(h);
                int Bh= Color.blue(h);
                int avgH=Gh+Bh/3;
                int OverAllAvgGB=avgA+avgB+avgC+avgD+avg+avgE+avgF+avgG+avgH/9;
                int OverAllAvgR=Red+Ra+Rb+Rc+Rd+Re+Rf+Rg+Rh;

                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(Red,Green,Blue));

                textView.setText("Red("+Red+")\n"+"Green("+Green+")\n"+"Blue("+Blue+")\n\n"+"X("+x+")\n"+"Y("+y+")"+"\n\n"+
                        "        \n"+"Width("+wi+")"+"   "+"Height("+hi+")\n"+
                        "Color Matrix\n"+
                        avgA+"  "+avgB+"  "+avgC+"\n"+
                        avgD+"  "+avg+"  "+avgE+"\n"+
                        avgF+"  "+avgG+"  "+avgH+"\n"+
                        " NEIGHBOURS GB="+OverAllAvgGB+"\n"+
                        "OVERALL Red="+OverAllAvgR+"\n"

                );

            }

            return true;
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: yes i have edited my question.sorry

Answer (score 0):

For finding slop of any straight line you require the index of touching the screen and leaving the screen. where screen is touched `ACTION_DOWN` event is thrown and when screen is left then `ACTION_UP` is thrown. Here `(x1,y1)` is stored when screen is touched and `(x2,y2)` is calculated when you leave the screen. Now you can find the slop using these two indices by slop equation :

```
m (slop of any straight line) = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
```

Here is some source code, I hope you find it helpful.

```
int x1,x2,y1,y2; 
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction()== event.ACTION_DOWN){
                x1 = (int) event.getX();
                y1 = (int) event.getY();
        }
        if(event.getAction()== event.ACTION_UP){
                x2 = (int) event.getX();
                y2 = (int) event.getY();
                double slop = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
        }
}
```

Comment: could you kindly explain your answer?

Comment: yes i get your answer. thank you . but that is on touch event i want to calculate slope as camera moves its code for a robot .camera is on head of robot and it will move in corridor if slop of both line in given image is same that means robot is in center i want answer in that case by using red color tiles .and calculation will not be on touch event but by changing image position on run time......sorry if did not explain well can u help me in that case